# UITableViewCell Label's content missing

Tags: swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I am setting a tableView but when running the app, the label's content is not stable, sometimes it shows full content, sometimes it doesn't. Looking for advise.
I attached the images for .xib setup and how tableView is displayed.
The code is my ViewController
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Remaining Last Statement Balance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$22198.45"
        case 1:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Minimum Payment Due"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2222198.45"
        case 2:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Current Ballance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2198.45"
        case 3:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Last Statement Balance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2198.45"
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you embed your labels in a horizontal stack view:

[image]

Stack view settings:

[image]

As you see... far fewer constraints to set.

You will also want to set the content Hugging and Compression Resistance priorities on the labels...

Title Label:

[image]

Amount Label:

[image]

Here is the source for the cell XIB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21678"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="94" id="mQo-go-dfm" customClass="CustomTableViewCell" customModule="TBPreScroll" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="94"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="mQo-go-dfm" id="VQH-35-Ynp">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="94"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="16" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gyE-fR-4jD">
                        <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="353" height="72"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" verticalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Title" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="0" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wCe-WN-C6L">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="277" height="72"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.55634254220000001" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="1000" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Amount" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tBE-pD-h4s">
                                <rect key="frame" x="293" y="0.0" width="60" height="72"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.53920841880000003" green="0.97934550050000002" blue="0.93539970709999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="gyE-fR-4jD" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VQH-35-Ynp" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="IcT-FV-MXp"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="gyE-fR-4jD" secondAttribute="bottom" id="Kmb-iH-0hG"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="gyE-fR-4jD" secondAttribute="trailing" id="PNM-XS-qfi"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="gyE-fR-4jD" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="VQH-35-Ynp" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="rFD-8G-ZY2"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="amountLabel" destination="tBE-pD-h4s" id="bDf-1M-yrP"/>
                <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="wCe-WN-C6L" id="cSF-sO-EgO"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="307.63358778625951" y="10.563380281690142"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Then your cell class:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var amountLabel: UILabel!
}
```

and view controller class - slightly modified... I added a single-point red border around the table view so we can see its frame. In storyboard, I inset the table view 20-points on all 4 sides for clarity:

```
class CustomTableWithXIBViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        
        // don't need these
        //tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        //tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        // let's add a border to the table view
        //  so we can see its frame at run-time
        tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Remaining Last Statement Balance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$22198.45"
        case 1:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Minimum Payment Due"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2222198.45"
        case 2:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Current Ballance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2198.45"
        case 3:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Last Statement Balance"
            cell.amountLabel.text = "$2198.45"
        default:
            break
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DonMag,  this is a very good solution